# Regex for alphanumeric with special character (-) and allow only maximum of 4 numeric characers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help creating a regex that allows alphanumeric characters with one special character (-) and should restrict the numeric characters to maximum 4.

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z,-]\d{0,4}$
```

Comment: Is the special character required? Why is comma character `,` in character set?

Comment: Where shoud the hyphen occur?

Comment: Can you add some example inputs and indicate whether the match should be successful or fail?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^(?!(.*\d){5,})[a-z0-9-]+$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `(?!.*\d{5,})` - Condition to check more than 4 digit.
- `[a-z0-9-]` - Matches `a` to `z`, `0` to `9`, and `-` one or more time.
- `$` - Anchor to end of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QfU2rr/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is not fulfilling my requirement.  I need below combinations:     Allowed (C1234,C23,C-123,C1,1234,123), Not allowed (C12345,12345,C123456). The number of numeric characters should be 4 maximum.

Comment: @user3303066 this works https://regex101.com/r/QfU2rr/5/ check here, i don't why you're saying so ?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z-]*[0-9a-zA-Z-]{0,4}[a-zA-Z-]*$
```

I don't know if I completely understood your requirements...
However, this javascript regexp pattern accepts any number of any case alphabetic characters (included the hyphen "-"), and at most 4 digits; all characters (alphabetics, hyphen, digits) can occurr in any order.